# What exactly does <packaging>grails-app<packaging> do?

Tags: java, maven, grails, dependencies, packaging

I understand how some of the other packaging configurations work with regard to maven builds, but I am confused on what the purpose and goals of this option is.
I have a grails project that I am able to run using the run-app command line commands, however it crashes during maven goals(clean install).
This could be related to another issue, however I want to understand at the root of things, how Maven is attempting this build, and this particular feature I am clueless on and unable to find information with Google searches.

Simply put, what is this packaging doing/producing, and how is maven managing it?